# How to delete an xml nodes by particular id in php

Tags: php, xml

This is the php code

```
    <?php
     function delete_book_id($id, $filename = 'books.xml'){
       $data = simplexml_load_file($filename);
       for($i = 0, $length = count($data->resource->book); $i < $length; $i++){
      if($data->resource->book[$i]->ID == $id){
      unset($data->resource->book[$i]);
      break;
    }
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $data->saveXML());
    }
   //SAMPLE USAGE
    delete_book_id('$id');
   ?>
```

XML file are following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalogue>
<resource>
  <book>
     <ID>Book 1</ID>
     <date>today</date>
     <retdate>tomorrow</retdate>
     <SID>Student 1</SID>
  </book>
   <book>
     <ID>Book 2</ID>
     <date>toda</date>
     <retdate>tomorro</retdate>
     <SID>Student 2</SID>
  </book>

  </resource>
  </catalogue>
```

Please Help me to get an answer.

Comment: '$id' needs to be "$id" or just $id.

Answer (score 2):

Change below :

```
delete_book_id('$id');
```

To:

```
delete_book_id($id);
```

Worked for me.

Comment: its showing an error like this :Notice: Undefined variable: id

Comment: Define this variable before call to function like : 
$id = "Book 1"; 
delete_book_id($id);